# How to give users authorisation to access specific fields/objects of the Model Form at /admin in django? Display particular fields in the html page

Tags: python, django, database

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

CHOICES = (('1','Earned Leave'),('2','Casual Leave'),('3','Sick Leave'),('4','Paid Leave'))

class Leave(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null =True)
    employee_ID = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    department = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    type_of_leave = models.CharField(max_length = 15, choices = CHOICES, default = None)
    from_date = models.DateField(help_text = 'mm/dd/yy')
    to_date = models.DateField(help_text = 'mm/dd/yy')
    reporting_manager = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = None, help_text = '0001_manager, 0002_manager')
    reason = models.CharField(max_length= 180)
    accepted = models.BooleanField(('approval status'), default= False)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I want the user to only access the 'type_leave_field' after submitting the form, when he is given 'is staff' status.

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from lrequests import models

class LeaveRequestForm(forms.ModelForm): 

    class Meta:
         fields = ("name", "employee_ID", "department", "designation", "type_of_leave", "from_date", "to_date", "reporting_manager", "reason")
    model = models.Leave
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import LeaveRequestForm

from .models import Leave

def leaveRequest(request):
    form_class = LeaveRequestForm
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LeaveRequestForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            leave = form.save(commit = False)
            leave.user = request.user
            form.save()
        return HttpResponse("Sucessfully submitted")
    else:
        form = LeaveRequestForm()
        return render(request, "request_form.html", {'form' : form_class})
```

I've tried using django-guardian and django-objectpermissions, but I've not seen the exact way of using them. I've even created a user-permission for it, but as the admin views and templates are not user-written code, I couldn't give a defnition.

base : It is a leave management system project, where a user can edit his type of leave even after submitting the form, thanks.

## update -

How do I display particular fields in the html page.

from my models.py the 'accepted' field is a Boolean field, after the user submits the form I want to display the field's status , whether it is True or False in a html page. I'm unable to retrieve that field from the db..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is override the ModelAdmin readonly_fields method by making all other fields read only except the one the user should be able to update.

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    # the logged in user can be accessed through the request object 
    if obj and request.user.is_staff:
        readonly_fields = [f.name for f in self.opts.fields]
        readonly_fields.remove('type_leave_field')
        return readonly_fields
```

Regarding the list comprehension:

`self.opts` gives you access to the Model specified in your Meta class (or `@admin.register()` should also be fine).

`self.opts.fields` is a tuple consisting of field objects from that model. Each object is a dictionary with meta data of a field. By accessing the .name (key) of each field object we can get the field name represented as a string.

Comment: Thanks it works like charm, but could you please explain me in detail the list comprehension you have used (self.opt.field and f.name)

Comment: I have updated the answer, hope this clarifies things a bit more.

Comment: could you give an idea with my updated question and yes that explanation helped me, thanks.

Comment: I am not completely sure what you mean by the user's html page?

Comment: I just want to display it (the status of the field) in a HTML page.